# Why can't MATLAB find insertShape and detectMinEigenFeatures even though I have Computer Vision Toolbox installed?

Tags: matlab, matlab-cvst

I have a problem with MATLAB version R2012b. Both `insertShape` and `detectMinEigenFeatures` are functions of "Computer Vision System Toolbox". I have installed "Computer Vision System Toolbox". Here is the output of `ver`, showing all the toolboxes installed.

```
MATLAB Version: 8.0.0.783 (R2012b)
MATLAB License Number: 724504
Operating System: Microsoft Windows 7 Version 6.2 (Build 9200)
Java Version: Java 1.6.0_17-b04 with Sun Microsystems Inc. Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM mixed mode

MATLAB                                                Version 8.0        (R2012b)
Simulink                                              Version 8.0        (R2012b)
Bioinformatics Toolbox                                Version 4.2        (R2012b)
Computer Vision System Toolbox                        Version 5.1        (R2012b)
Curve Fitting Toolbox                                 Version 3.3        (R2012b)
DSP System Toolbox                                    Version 8.3        (R2012b)
Fuzzy Logic Toolbox                                   Version 2.2.16     (R2012b)
Global Optimization Toolbox                           Version 3.2.2      (R2012b)
Image Processing Toolbox                              Version 8.1        (R2012b)
MATLAB Builder NE                                     Version 4.1.2      (R2012b)
MATLAB Compiler                                       Version 4.18       (R2012b)
MATLAB Report Generator                               Version 3.13       (R2012b)
Mapping Toolbox                                       Version 3.6        (R2012b)
Neural Network Toolbox                                Version 8.0        (R2012b)
Optimization Toolbox                                  Version 6.2.1      (R2012b)
Parallel Computing Toolbox                            Version 6.1        (R2012b)
Signal Processing Toolbox                             Version 6.18       (R2012b)
Spreadsheet Link EX                                   Version 3.1.6      (R2012b)
Statistics Toolbox                                    Version 8.1        (R2012b)
System Identification Toolbox                         Version 8.1        (R2012b)
Wavelet Toolbox
```

The code that I test is this:

```
%Create System objects for reading and displaying video and for drawing a bounding box of the object.
videoFileReader = vision.VideoFileReader('visionface.avi');
videoPlayer = vision.VideoPlayer('Position', [100, 100, 680, 520]);

%Read the first video frame, which contains the object, define the region.
objectFrame = step(videoFileReader);
objectRegion = [264, 122, 93, 93];

%As an alternative, you can use the following commands to select the object region using a mouse. The object must occupy the majority of the region. 
figure; imshow(objectFrame);
objectRegion=round(getPosition(imrect))

%Show initial frame with a red bounding box.
objectImage = insertShape(objectFrame, 'Rectangle', objectRegion,'Color', 'red'); 
figure; imshow(objectImage); title('Yellow box shows object region');

%Detect interest points in the object region.
points = detectMinEigenFeatures(rgb2gray(objectFrame), 'ROI', objectRegion);
```

When I run this code I get this error:

> Undefined function 'insertShape' and 'detectMinEigenFeatures' for
>   input arguments of type 'single' and 'double'

What is the problem?

Answer (score 4):

It seems like both `detectMinEigenFeatures` and `insertShape` were introduced as of matlab version `r2013a`. You are running `r2012b`, where these function did not yet exist in the computer vision toolbox.

So if you are able to upgrade to `r2013a` I think your problem should be solved.

Answer (score 2):

There is a workaround in R2012b.  You can user the vision.CornerDetector system object, which also implements the min-eigen value corner detection algorithm.